# How to create foreign key relationship in HttpPost request to web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Given the following models:

```cs
public class Account
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal StartingBalance { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Transaction
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public string Memo { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
    public Account Account { get; set; }
}
```

A transaction has an associated Tag and Account.  EF correctly creates the database relationship with `AccountId` and `TagId` columns in the Transaction table.

I am trying to do a post request to the following controller method:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Transaction>> PostTransaction(Transaction transaction)
{
    _context.Transactions.Add(transaction);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetTransaction), new { id = transaction.Id }, transaction);
}
```

Postman request:

```
{
    "accountId": 1,
    "amount": 111.0,
    "memo": "My transaction",
    "tagId": 1
}
```

It seems I can't create a foreign key relationship between the transaction and the associated Account and Tag.  Both properties are null in the created transaction.  I have tried adding additional arguments to the controller method but I can't find where to access those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Both properties are null in the created transaction.

It because of The way you create the postman request is not correct.

According to your models, the request should have a structure like below:

```
{
    "Account": {
        "accountId": 1,
    },
    "Amount": 111.0,
    "Memo": "My transaction",
    "Tag": {
        "tagId": 1
    },
}
```

Actually `Account` and `Tag` aren't primitive data type and they are Object type, so you should create JSON object for them and pass their attributes to you API `PostTransaction`. then the JSON you passed automatically map to `Transaction` model and the `AccountId` and `TagId` fields will have value.

Comment: Thanks Saeed.  When posting using your structure, the foreign key relationships are created, but they are created to brand new instances of `Account` and `Tag`, as opposed to the FK I've passed in.

Comment: before committing the transaction, Have you the records `Tag` with id 1 and `Account` with id 1 in the database? I need more information to say what's wrong. but based on what you said, it seems another problem that not related to your current posted question. in this question you created bad formatted JSON of you actual model so framework couldn't map JSON fields to Models, then you got null on the id fields.

Comment: Yes the tag and account IDs in the request exist in the database.  I believe you are correct that my issue now lies with another area of my code so I've marked your response as the answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I presumed that records for `Tag` and `Account` with `Id` 1 are already exist in database tables.

You are getting `Account` & `Tag` objects as `null` because you haven't pass those values in request and the same object you return to your response.

Instead you can get updated object from the `_context` with `.Include(x => x.Account).Include(x => x.Tag)` and send it in response like below.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Transaction>> PostTransaction(Transaction transaction)
{
    _context.Transactions.Add(transaction);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    transaction = await _context.Transactions.Include(x => x.Account).Include(x => x.Tag).FindAsync(transaction.Id);
    return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetTransaction), new { id = transaction.Id }, transaction);
}
```

Comment: When structuring the JSON data as Saeed suggested, related `Tag` and `Account` entities are returned.  However, the tags and accounts returned are always newly created.

Comment: Ohh. Here I presumed that records for `Tag` and `Account` with `Id` 1 are already exist in database tables. In such case my answer will work. But if you want to create new records for `Tag` and `Account` then you must follow @Saeed's answer.

Answer (score 0):

For inserting `Transaction` with foreign key, you need to append the foreign properties.

For return the relation property, you need to query with `Include` like

1. Model

   ```
   public class Account
   {
       public long Id { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public decimal StartingBalance { get; set; }
   }

   public class Tag
   {
       public long Id { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
   }

   public class Transaction
   {
       public long Id { get; set; }
       public decimal Amount { get; set; }
       public string Memo { get; set; }
       public long? TagId { get; set; }
       public Tag Tag { get; set; }
       public long? AccountId { get; set; }
       public Account Account { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Query

   ```
   [HttpGet]
   public async Task<Transaction> GetTransaction(Transaction transaction)
   {
       return transaction;
   }
   [HttpPost]
   public async Task<ActionResult<Transaction>> PostTransaction(Transaction transaction)
   {
       _context.Transactions.Add(transaction);
       await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
       transaction = await _context.Transactions.Include(t => t.Account).Include(t => t.Tag).FirstAsync(t => t.Id == transaction.Id);
       return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetTransaction), new { id = transaction.Id }, transaction);
   }
   ```
3. Request

   ```
   {
       "AccountId": 2,
       "Amount": 111.0,
       "Memo": "My transaction",
       "TagId":2
   }
   ```